# When the RSI is Divergence, I want the position not to open until the certain candle time expires

Tags: pine-script-v5

In a Pine script,
I am running dca strategy within 1 minute time frame. When the RSI Deviation occurs in a different time frame (for example, 1 hour), I want the position not to be opened until the certain candle period ends (for example, 40 minutes). How can I do that

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do a manual check the time of the current candle in the different time frame and only open a position if the candle has completed.

```
timeFrame = 40m
timeRSIDeviation = 60m

timeFrame = time(timeFrame)
timeRSIDeviation = time(timeRSIDeviation)
currentTime = timestamp()
rsiDeviationOccurred = (currentTime > timeRSIDeviation)

if (rsiDeviationOccurred and currentTime == timeFrame)
    strategy.entry("DCA", strategy.long)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.

but this is not the correct answer.
my question:

I want to stop position entries for a certain candle time after RSI Deviation occurs.

I know this but I can't apply it
"if entry  and not (bar_index - rsiDeviationOccurred >= 40)"

Comment: How do I set the variable "rsiDeviationOccurred"?